# What would be causing a checkbox to ignore its checked value?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to initialize an html checkbox's `checked` value to false. However when I try to set it and then log its value immediately after, it still appears as true, and the checkbox is remaining checked.

What could be causing the `checked` property to ignore explicitly settings its value via JavaScript?

```
console.log( "setting", self.checkbox.testid, "to", self.checked );
self.checkbox.checked = self.checked;
console.log( self.checkbox.testid + " checked: ", self.checkbox.checked ); // still true
```

Comment: Can you replicate in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It seems to work fine in a fiddle, implying something else is in my framework is causing it to fail. At this point I'm looking for thoughts on what could possibly be happening elsewhere. I've run into a similar problem where a click event was accidentally getting canceled, but in this case I'm programmatically setting it and it's failing somehow but I can't understand how that could even be possible.

Comment: Maybe `self.checkbox` is **not** the element you think you're dealing with..

Comment: @chaiguy Post the fiddle as additional details to your post so everyone can see it.

Comment: @David I considered that, but I'm logging the very same self.checkbox's checked property immediately after setting it and it's still not working.

Comment: You probably won't get any answers without more code. Namely, the HTML and where the JavaScript is placed. As @David suggests, sharing the fiddle would help everyone out, especially people who find this question in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Try some other method:

If you happen to be using jQuery:

```
$('#myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

or if not, try to set a ID on the checkbox and assure you are dealing with the right element:

```
document.getElementById('myCheckbox').checked = false;
```

Comment: @ianpgall Not a good assumption. What about beginners who know nothing about it?

Comment: @David Sorry, I thought you'd realize my sarcasm :)

Comment: I realized my mistake after posting, and thats why I edited it into code that could be run without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! The problem lied in fact not in the `checked` property of the checkbox, but the *value* I was attempting to set it to.

If I change `self.checked` to `false` explicitly, it now works. So the question is why is it getting logged as "false" but that "false" value is not actually `false`!

...

Yes indeed, when I log `typeof self.checked` it is in fact a *string* that has a value of "false"! And of course the string "false" is in fact truthy. How deceptive!

Now the question is why the heck is self.checked a string, but that's my own problem to solve. Thanks for helping me think it through folks.

Comment: There is no mention of `self.checked` in the question and the code shows a boolean literal `false` being used. Just saying that actual code is always useful to put in your questions :P

Comment: Whoops you're right--I simplified it by removing it in the sample code not thinking it could have actually been the problem. I put it back in so the answer makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to cross-browser change checkbox's value programatically you need to do this:

```
checkbox.checked = checkbox.defaultChecked = false;
```

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of that.